# Using OpenFileDialog in C# Dll

Tags: c#

I want to implement a file picker into my dll. Is there a solution for this? I can't import `System.Windows.Forms` as this is a dll.

Thanks for the help

Comment: This question is very light on detail, as well as demonstration of effort. Please make it clear what you need your code to do, and show what you have tried. As an aside, just because something is a dll does not mean it cannot reference System.Windows.Forms.

Comment: Well, quite simple: I will give my extension input which should be saved in a file that can be selected in a file picker. I tried to import System.Windows.Forms but Visual Studio says that the type or namespace Forms doesn't exists in the namespace System.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add it as a reference to your project.

Project ->Add Reference -> Assemblies -> Check System.Windows.Forms ->
OK

Then you can import it by

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Comment: Thanks! Let me guess the rarely used stuff is excluded from libraries to shrink the size of the library, right?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to tie a library function to a UI framework.

Create an event instead, to which your application code subscribes and presents the user with a dialog or input that corresponds to the application's UI.

Comment: Well I have to. I can't "hack" into the programm ui and I can't modify it so this is sadly the only solution. Normally I won't do this because this should be in the GUI application and not in the library.